# oc rsync fails due to no space on the disk in /tmp storage

Tags: unix, openshift, rsync

I'm copying files from openshift pod to UNIX server. Files are in Giga Bytes size. I'm using oc rsync in Unix server. But, it's using /tmp directory as cache directory while copying. File size is greater than the /tmp directory size. Due to that, I'm getting "no space left on the device"

Is there is any way to bypass /tmp directory cache to different folder or can we totally avoid the cache?

Comment: You can try to set variable `TMP` or `TEMP` to point other directory with enough space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set variable `TMP` or `TEMP` to point other directory with enough space.
I am sure in documentation you will find mentioned the proper variable (if it's not in two above)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
export TMPDIR="folder were data should be cached"

oc rsync pod:source_path target_path
```

Thanks to @Romeo Ninov for pointing me in the right direction.